# Show the server-side generated HTML in a new window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

What is the best way to show the server-side generated HTML (full page) into a new popup window? It should be triggered upon clicking a button (causing a postback to the server).

Thanks

Edited:

The HTML content are dynamically generated in the code behind and the content is full page (`<html> ... </html>`). Upon clicking a button on the web page, I would like to get the generated html content and pass it to the browser and show it in a new popup window. The content will be the final result (UI) not HTML tags.

Comment: Like you want to show a "view source" in a new window?

Comment: I think he meant that he wants his server code to output something like `<div>abc<div>` into a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the same page with mime type `text/plain`

For instance with a

```
<a href="same url?mime=textonly" target="_blank">
```

On the asp server, when the argument mime=textonly is detected, you change the mime type to text/plain

Comment: +1 @Alain ... In fact, I don't need mime type text/plan since the result should be normal HTML page but your answer seems doable since I need to pass some parameters via querystring and popup window should be conjured up accordingly. In the Page_Load event, I could detect the querystring and call Response.Clear()/ClearContent(), flush out the generated content and end the response. Let me try out first.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I should have started with a comment to get more information but can you not:

Post back to a new window on click? `<a target="_blank">`

Though if the requirement is for the server to generate the new window, just append something like:
`<script>window.open('title'); </script>` at the end of the response and have the server populate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably have the server code save the HTML to a file and output `<script>window.open('urltothefile');</script>`. Just make sure that you write a unique filename each time.

Alternatively, you could have the server code store all related information into a database and output `<script>window.open('showResult.aspx?id=123');</script>`, where 123 is the id of the database record. Then in showResult.aspx, have it generate the required HTML.

Another option is to output the HTML into a div with `style="display: none"`, then have some javascript to assign the innerHTML to the newly opened window. eg:

```
var w = window.open ('_blank');
w.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("returnedHTML").innerHTML
```

One more possibility is to have a WebMethod. I don't really remember how to declare one, but it is a server function that can be called from the client. Open the window via javascript, call the webmethod and place the result as the innerHTML of the newly opened window; Pretty much like the previous option.

All these are good but they don't work when you use UpdatePanel and partial rendering. If that's the case, it's a whole different story.